# how can use vim-cmd command in esxi with ansible

Tags: python, ansible, esx

I have no vCenter, just esxi hosts

and I don't use any ansible inventory, I prefer add_host style
like below

```
- name: Set inventory from parameter
  gather_facts: no
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Set with add_host
    add_host:
      hostname: "{{ item.dest_name }}"
      ansible_host: "{{ item.dest_addr }}"
      ansible_user: "{{ item.dest_conn_user }}"
      ansible_password: "{{ item.dest_conn_pwd }}"
      ansible_dest_protocol: "{{ item.dest_protocol| default('') }}"
      ansible_port: "{{ item.dest_port | default('22') }}"
      ansible_host_key_checking: no
      custom_dest_name: "{{ item.dest_name }}"
      group: remote_org
    with_items: "{{ dests }}"

- name: Module test with set parameter
  gather_facts: no
  hosts: remote_org
  become: yes
  remote_user: root
  roles:
   - ../roles/4.get_vm_mac
```

ans my tasks/main file below

```
---
  - block:
    - name: Get Target VMid
      command: /bin/vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms
      delegate_to: localhost

    rescue:
    - name: 'When failure'
      debug:
        msg: "Try again"
```

and results

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

can you help me ?? :d

Answer (score 1):

I made a basic mistake

```
  - block:
    - name: Get Target VMid
      command: /bin/vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms
      #delegate_to: localhost <- delete this line
```

and now works

thank you everybody